# Upgrading SQL Server Express to Developer performance counter registry consistency error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, performancecounter

[image]

I am currently attempting to upgrade my version of SQL Server Express Edition to Developer edition.

I have come across this Failure message, can someone

A.) Explain is a basic clear way what this actually means so I can get my head around it.

and

B.) Suggest a solution for this problem

Comment: Did you go to the KB article and attempt to repair the problem? Seems to be exactly what the error message is clearly telling you to do: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300956

Comment: I did go to this however wanted to get my head around what the problem was first of all before I tried to change anything

Comment: I don't think anyone here has a time machine to go back and figure out when or why your performance counters went south. :-)

Comment: ok fair enough, could you explain what performance counter are perhaps and why they are corrupted, and also what this means?

Comment: You can read about performance counters here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373083%28v=vs.85%29.aspx Why they got corrupted? Again, I have no idea what happened on your system or when. The reason SQL Server won't proceed with setup is that it actually uses performance counters in both directions - it provides data to Windows for perfmon to see, and it also exposes performance counters to SQL Server via the DMV sys.dm_os_performance_counters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying an in-place upgrade, and in addition to repairing the counters via [the KB article mentioned in the error message](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300956), I suggest you install a proper instance of Developer Edition. Then back up your user databases from Express, restore them on Developer, and once you are happy that everything is working, uninstall Express Edition. In addition to avoiding peculiar upgrade issues when moving to a new edition *and* a new version (unless you don't really mean Express is SQL Server 2008), you also have the added bonus that you still have your original databases intact (which you won't have if the upgrade fails in worse ways than simply being blocked).

Answer (score 0):

This means that your keys:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows
>   NT\CurrentVersion\Perflib\Last Counter

and

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows
>   NT\CurrentVersion\Perflib\009

are different from each other.

[image]

Check If you have a  Disable Performance Counters key and set it to 0 (I deleted mine as you can see on the print screen)

Then rebuild  the Performance Counter by running:

```
cd %systemroot%\system32
lodctr /R
```

you can check if it worked on Performance Monitor by trying to add a SQl Server counter